# Is the port in Vladivostok ice-free all year round?

Tags: russia, winter, sailing, pacific-ocean, vladivostok

Is it possible to sail into Vladivostok all year round?  One source in [Wikipedia about Vladivostok says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladivostok#Port):

> The port is ice-free all year round

[Another source in Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russky_Bridge):

> The locality of the bridge crossing construction site is characterized by severe climate conditions: temperatures vary from -31 °C to 37 °C; storms bring winds of up to 36 m/s and waves of up to 6 m in height; and ice formations in winter can be up to 70 cm thick.

What to make of this? Is the port ice-free only because of [icebreakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icebreaker)?

Comment: Is this "[based on an actual problem you face](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" or is it just a curiousity about geography? The latter is off-topic.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, planning, but more or less day dreaming about a trip in the distant future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After the [ТЭЦ-2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%A2%D0%AD%D0%A6-2) (Thermal Power Plant - 2) was built in 1984, the port in Vladivostok ([Zolotoy Rog Bay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zolotoy_Rog)) is ice-free for almost the whole year. Before that, ice breakers helped making it ice-free.

Comment: @axsvl77 see my edits

Answer (score 20):

Vladivostok is not a warm-water port, but is kept ice free by ice breakers, according to [Encyclopedia.com](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Vladivostok.aspx), allowing shipping into the harbor. Vladivostock is Russia's major Pacific seaport, the main base of its Pacific fleet, and a base for fishing and, formerly, whaling fleets.

Comment: Russian *whaling fleets*?  Is this source a copy of the 1911 Encyclopædia Brittanica or so?

Comment: Having a Russian colleague whose name is abbreviated as *Vlad*, I had to parse the first sentence twice ;)

Comment: @Jan A first name as a part of the city name is not uncommon at all in Russia.

Comment: @gerrit late night dim light... although noting that Russian's in the East ares still permitted by IWC to hunt/catch up to 140 endangered gray whales annually. Putin & his crossbow http://www.reuters.com/article/us-russia-environment-putin-idUSTRE67O5ZT20100827